# flask server is truncating long json responses some of the times

Tags: http, nginx, flask, uwsgi

my route is fetching user tokens

```
GET /tokens
```

average response time is around 180ms and response is json. 
using Flask + nginx.

some requests, the response content is truncated at around 33kb, thus the JSON is malformed. some requests, with the **same parameters**, at nearly the **same time**, the response is ok at around 216kb.

My question is, why is this happening and why is this happening in an un consist way?

here is flask response code

```
class NormalResponse(Response):
    def __init__(self, response):
        super(NormalResponse, self).__init__(response, 200)

    res = json.dumps(paginator.paginate(tokens))

    return NormalResponse(res)
```

I found the issue related to nginx since the failed responses have this logs

```
2018/12/18 16:35:17 [crit] 16#16: *95010 open() "/var/tmp/nginx/uwsgi/1/42/0000000421" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 172.31.72.76, server: , request: "GET /tokens?limit=501&offset=0&order=desc&owner_id=11111 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/run/server.socket:", host: "oauth.dev.bla_bla.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved by adding

```
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/tmp/nginx
```

to the `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like response overflows [proxy_buffers](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffers) and tries to temporarily save it to [proxy_temp_path](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_temp_path) and your error message quite confirms it. You should check file permissions of nginx's user on that folder.

Comment: if it's related to permissions, then why not all requests fail, just part of them?

Comment: I suppose because nginx doesn't save all requests to disk, only part of them (huge ones?).

Comment: But the same request with roughly the same response size and the same parameters sent sometimes failing and sometimes not